# Advice with DatePicker code structure Android Studio

Tags: android, datepicker, onclicklistener

So I'm very new to android programming, and have no real experience with software building however I do have a basic background with PHP so I get some of the theory behind it all.

I'm currently making a basic Form activity that will store the entries into a DB, which can be recalled in another activity where it can be viewed and edited etc etc.

I have found lots of helpful advice to get to where I am but currently having trouble with how I need to structure the code to implement the DatePicker dialog, the problem I'm facing is the example code for the date picker has

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
```

Where as the code in my project is `public class New extends ActionBarActivity {`

So when I edit the line to "implements OnClickListener" my spinner drop downs don't like it.

I have tried entering the code in without the "implements OnClickListener"

Please take a look at what I have and point me in the right direction, I need to understand where its going wrong and how it should be structured.

```
public class New extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
```

//Product List

```
Spinner productList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.product);

String[] products = new String[] { "1", "2", "3" };

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, products);

    productList.setAdapter(adapter);

    productList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
            Log.v("products", (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

//Reason List

```
Spinner reasonList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.reason);

String[] reasons = new String[] { "A", "B", "C" };

ArrayAdapter<String> adapters = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, reasons);

reasonList.setAdapter(adapters);

reasonList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                               int position, long id) {
        Log.v("reasons", (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

//Start Date Picker

```
    private EditText StartDate;

    private DatePickerDialog StartdatePickerDialog;

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);

        dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);

        findViewsById();

        setDateTimeField();
    }

private void findViewsById() {

    StartDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.startdate);
    StartDate.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    StartDate.requestFocus();

}

private void setDateTimeField() {
    StartDate.setOnClickListener(this);

    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    StartdatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            StartDate.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
        }

    }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == StartDate) {
        StartDatePickerDialog.show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, try removing the `implements OnClickListener` from your activity and replacing

```
    StartDate.setOnClickListener(this);
```

with

```
    StartDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(view == StartDate) {
                StartDatePickerDialog.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

and removing the `onclick` method in Start Date Picker. Basically, what `implements OnClickListener` does is that it can be attached to components (the `EditText`, in this case) which, when clicked, will be redirected to your implementation of `onClick`. You're replacing your `Activity` listener (which can be used by any component in that activity via `setOnClickListener(this)`) with a specific listener designed for the `StartDate` alone. Note how your spinners all have `onItemSelectedListeners`, which work on the same basic principle.

Words are hard, let me know if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank You, this has given me a better idea on the situation. I will have a tidy up and a play around and hopefully can see some results. I will update my progress.

Comment: Awesome, got it all sorted. Thanks for your help, much appriciated